# Using global variables in nodered Javascript (HowTo)

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm trying to using a make a lock variable in Node-Red. for that I've wrote the following function!

```
 global.set('lockvariable',0);


 var payload  = msg.payload; 
 if (msg.payload[0].value === 0  && global.get('lockvariable')=== 0){
    msg.payload  =global.get('lockvariable');  
    global.set('lockvariable',1);

 } else if (global.get('lockvariable') === 1){
    msg.payload = global.get('lockvariable');

 }
 return msg;
```

The Problem that I have is that the return value is always 0. I guess because I'm writing the initialization the first line ! since I'm from the C world I don't get what I'm missing here!

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialise a global variable you probably want to do it on a separate flow with and inject node set to fire on Node-RED startup to trigger it.

The other option is to gate the setting at the start of the function with a test to see if the context variable has already been set.

```
if (global.get("lockvariable") == undefined) {
  global.set('lockvariable',0);
}
...
```